# Program that will ask the user to enter size of the array, show all the values entered and tell if its positive or negative

Tags: java, arrays, joptionpane

I have this assignment for tomorrow and I'm a beginner please help. Must be JOptionpane :O I was wondering if I can use if else statement in showmessagedialog. Error says incompatible types required: int ( for holder=holder + "\n" + aw[x];
Here's what I've done so far(SORRY I'M A BEGINNER PLS UNDERSTAND):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 String s;
 int size;
 int size2;
 int holder;
 s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the size of the array");
 size = Integer.parseInt(s);
 String aw[]= new String[size];

 for (int x=0; x<=aw.length-1; x++){
     aw[x]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for array[" + x + "]");
     size2 = Integer.parseInt(aw[x]);
 }
    for (int x=0; x<=aw.length-1;x++)
    {
        holder=holder + "\n" + aw[x];




    }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, if (holder<0)  { holder + " is negative" }  else holder " is positive");

}
```

}'

Comment: Try using a `Scanner` instead of `Integet.parseInt`.

Comment: Side note: `x <= aw.length - 1` is the same as `x < aw.length`

Answer (score 0):

holder is declared as an int, but in

```
holder=holder + "\n" + aw[x];
```

you try to assign it a String.

Answer (score 0):

Use String to store your messge

```
String msg;
if (holder<0)
{  
    msg = holder + " is negative"; 
}  
else
{
     msg = holder " is positive";   
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);
```

showMessageDialog function expects the second parameter to be String

Comment: No need to initialize msg to "".  It's getting overwritten, just declare it: String msg;

Answer (score 0):

Something you can not do:

1 Variable `holder` you declare is int type. It can not be used to do `+`` operation.

2 Two for -loop is not neccessary.

3 **You forget to check whether the number entered is zero**, you just have positive and negative logic.

4 When trying to use `+` opeartion for strings. Please use `append` method of `StringBuilder`.

Here is the code made based on the above 3 items.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s;
    int size;
    int size2;
    int holder = 0;

    s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the size of the array");
    size = Integer.parseInt(s);
    String aw[] = new String[size];

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int x = 0; x <= aw.length - 1; x++) {
        aw[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter value for array[" + x
                + "]");
        size2 = Integer.parseInt(aw[x]);

        if(size2 ==0)
        {
            sb.append(aw[x]).append(" is zero").append('\n');
        }else if(size2 >0)
        {
            sb.append(aw[x]).append(" is positive").append('\n');
        }else
        {
            sb.append(aw[x]).append(" is negative").append('\n');
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sb.toString());

  }
```

[image]

Comment: one  more  thing,  please accept  an answer if one of  the answer has solved your problem.  in  this   way,  the  question will be  off unanswered topic.  others donot  need to  care  about it.  :)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is:

```
final String msg = holder == 0 ? "is zero" : (holder > 0 ? "is positive" : "is negative");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,msg);
```